# Computation of surfaces areas of some objects

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I want to calculate the surface area of the following objects:

1) A cylinder with height $h$ and radius $r$

2) A cone $C=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2+y^2=z^2, 0<z<4\}$

3) A torus

At first i need parameterizations of the surface areas of the objects.

Can someone explain me what the basic idea is to get them?

**Edit**:

My topics in analysis are at the moment manifolds and integrals (on submanifolds) like curves in $\mathbb R^2$.

I got the following definition which i want to use:

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a submanifold, $U \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ open and $\phi$ be a parametrisation of M with $\phi(U)=M$.

A subset $E \subseteq M$ is called measurable if $\phi^{-1}(E)$ is measurable. If $E\subseteq M$ is measurable then:

$$ \int_{\phi^{-1}(E)}^{} \! \sqrt{\mbox{det}(G(x))}  \, dx$$

the k-dimensional volume of E. $(G(x):=J_x(\phi)^{T}J_x(\phi))$ with the Jacobi matrix $J_x(\phi)$ of $\phi$ in x.

Comment: 1) should need no integration. 2) has circular base with $r = 4$, probably also elementary.

Comment: Just edited above. If more informations are needed, pls tell me

Comment: I have to dry my tears first. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cylinder mantle $C_M$ we consider the following parametrization:

$\phi:(0,2\pi)\times(0,h)\rightarrow C_M \subseteq\mathbb R^3$,with $\Phi(\phi,z)=(Rcos(\phi),Rsin(\phi),z)$. The jacobi matrix is then:

$$M(\phi,z)=\begin{pmatrix} -Rsin(\phi) & 0 &  \\ Rcos(\phi) & 0 &  \\ 0 & 1 &   \end{pmatrix}$$

and $$det(M^{T}M)=det\begin{pmatrix} R^2 & 0 &  \\ 0 & 1 &  \end{pmatrix}=R^2 $$

We obtain now:

$$\int_{(0,2\pi)\times (0,h)}^{} \! \sqrt{R^2}, d(x,y)=\int_0^{2\pi} \! \int_0^h \! r \, dx  \, dx  = 2\pi Rh$$

The areas of the two circles are $\pi R^2$. So for the surface area of the cylinder we get:

$2\pi Rh+2\pi R^2=2\pi R(h+R)$ and we are done.

Comment: Seems good. the result is correct. How u got that parametrization?

Comment: These are cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Could you also give a solution for the torus pls?

Answer (score 0):

Note: this was written before the tools / setting were specified in more detail.

Like fellow user Rory Dalton already wrote, the basic idea is creating the area out of revolving curves or summing up parts of suitable differential surface elements. The latter method is a bit fishy, at least I feel guilt when I consider the rigourness, but it is often working.

OK, let us the cylinder mantle, to see if that is in the style you need.

A differential surface area element of the mantle is $dA$ with
$$
dA = 2 \pi r\, dh$$
which gives 
$$
A_M = \int\limits_0^h dA = 
2 \pi r \int\limits_0^h dh = 2 \pi r h 
$$

for top and bottom we have each
$$
A_t = \int_0^r 2\pi \rho d\rho = 2\pi \frac{1}{2} r^2 = \pi r^2
$$

gives 
$A = A_M + A_t + A _b = 2\pi r h + 2 \pi r^2 = 2\pi(r h +r^2)$.

*(other trivial stuff deleted)*

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your effort! But I dont think this is the way i have to solve the tasks. The topic is. "Integration on sub manifolds". And i want to get a parametrization like: $Cylinder:\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 : .... \}$ Then i want to use the formular: $\int_{\phi^{-1}(E)}^{} \! \sqrt{det(G(x))}  \, dx$ , where $G(x)=J_x(\phi)^{T}J_x(\phi)$ is the jacobi matrix of $\phi$ in x. I will add more information in my question above.

Comment: But on the other hand, that it is not much worse, as the differential elements are hidden in the Jacobian, and the determinant is probably the volume factor from the coordinate transformation. Looks like it needs coordinate transformation.

Comment: Cylinder parametrization should be $x^2 + y^2 = r \wedge z \in [0, h]$ for the mantle, $x^2 + y^2 \le r \wedge z \in \{0, h\}$ at top and bottom, or?

Comment: i added all the informations in the question above

Answer (score 0):

Each of those objects can be derived by moving a circle through 3D space, perhaps changing its size as well. If you are doing this problem you should already know several ways to parameterize a circle with one variable, given its center and radius. The cylinder is the circle moved straight up from the x-y plane, the cone is the same except the radius changes linearly, and the torus is an off-center circle rotated around the x (or y) axis. This gives two variables for each parameterization. You should be able to continue from there.